# Correct way to reduce dimension in dice loss

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, image-segmentation, semantic-segmentation

I am confused how to reduce dimenisons in dice loss function for segmentation.
Here is input shape `(B,C,H,W)`
and there are two ways to reduce
**Sum spatial dimension only first, then take the mean of batch and channels**

```
reduce_axis=[2,3]
denominator = torch.sum(true, dim=reduce_axis) + torch.sum(pred, dim=reduce_axis)
dice=1.0 - (2.0 * intersection + smooth) / (denominator + smooth)
torch.mean(dice)  # the batch and channel average
```

**Sum all dimensions first except batch then average batch**

```
reduce_axis=[1,2,3]
denominator = torch.sum(true, dim=reduce_axis) + torch.sum(pred, dim=reduce_axis)
dice=1.0 - (2.0 * intersection + smooth) / (denominator + smooth)
torch.mean(dice)  # the batch and channel average
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the meaning of the different dimensions.
If your channel dimension means segmentation masks of different classes (aka ["semantic segmentation"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33953195/1714410)), then computing Dice per-channel and then averaging over channels and batch will give you the mean Dice per-class.
Alternatively, if you compute dice over channels as well (2nd option), you have a multi-class Dice (I'm not sure if this is even a "thing") and you report the average of it over the batch.

What is it that you want to compute?