# Semantic Segmentation or Object Detection?

Tags: computer-vision, object-detection, image-segmentation, semantic-segmentation

I'm working on a project which I try to detect and track the herds of sheep and goat. I'm in dilemma about using Semantic Segmentation or Object Detection. Large number of sheep/goat are close to each other and there is an average 80-90 sheep/goat in a single frame. Which one do you think best suits for my problem?

In addition, do you have any model you recommend? (First priority is accuracy.)

Comment: explain the goal/reasons for doing this. that'll help give usable advice.

Comment: I want to count how many sheeps/goats passed. (in video)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Semantic** segmentation will do you no good: [The goal of *semantic*-segmentation is to label each pixel in the image to its semantic class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33947823/what-is-semantic-segmentation-compared-to-segmentation-and-scene-labeling). Therefore, *all* goats in the frame will have the same label "goat", and *all* sheep will have the same label "sheep".
What you might be considering is **Instance**-segmentation: In this task, the goal is not only to associate each pixel with its semantic class (as in *semantic* segmentation), but additionally to be able to set apart different instances of the same class. In your example, a good semantic segmentation will be able not only to label all goat pixels as "goats", but to separate the different goats in the frame accurately.

A very popular semantic segmentation approach is [mask-RCNN](https://paperswithcode.com/paper/mask-r-cnn): it's basically a two-stage system. First, it detects the different objects and then provides a segmentation mask for each individual bounding box. This might be a good starting point for your project: It will allow you to compare your counts based on the detection or the *instance*-segmentation output of the model.

Answer (score 3):

The COCO dataset has a class for sheep (class_id=20) so you should be able to use an object detection model pre-trained on the COCO dataset.

Then, count up the number of objects labelled with class_id=20

Tensorflow Hub has lots of pre-trained models like this. For example FasterRCNN+InceptionResNet V2 has higher accuracy, or ssd+mobilenet V2 is smaller and faster.