# Fully convolutional net in Caffe

Tags: caffe, matcaffe

Is it possible for me to directly give an image and its segmentation as the input for training a caffe?
Does the original implementation support this? 
If yes where can I find an appropreate prototxt file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Image per-pixel Scene labeling output issue (using FCN-32s Semantic Segmentation)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32451934/image-per-pixel-scene-labeling-output-issue-using-fcn-32s-semantic-segmentation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It is possible.

Have a look at [Fully Convolutional Networks for Semantic Segmentation](https://github.com/shelhamer/fcn.berkeleyvision.org) and [SegNet](https://github.com/alexgkendall/caffe-segnet). They are both fully convolutional networks and are trained for semantic segmentation. The prototxt and caffemodel files are available on GitHub.

You can run FCN with the original implementation, but SegNet uses some layers which are not part of the original implementation. They have an edited version of caffe on Github, so you can use that.